# PNG animation issue on iOs and macOS (CSS3 + jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, png

First, sorry for my english. I'm from Russia, I've tried to get answer on russian version of Stack Overflow, but no success.

Right now I'm doing a website on my work. It contains a lot of heavy images and visual effects (according to designer's layout). While I was testing the main page, I ran into strange bug. It is very difficult to catch it, but our designer saw it on his iPhone XS max and iMac with Retina display 5K. Me on my Xiaomi Redmi 4A, iMac Retina 4K and Macbook Air 17 couldn't catch it.

Please, take a look at the screenshot. How this block works: we have three pictures, when user swipes left or right, they are moving, and centered image is scaling to 110%. I'm doing it via CSS3 and jQuery.

It looks like a trace from immediately stopped vehicle. Does anybody now why this happening? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Images are in PNG. On screenshot you can see two normal states and one with bug. Bug was captured on iPhone XS max, normal states are captured in Chrome Developer mode (simulating iPhone 6/7/8 plus).

Thank you

Link to picture:
[Bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiVeB.jpg)

Comment: Can't confirm the problem from your description, can you provide your code?

Comment: @dawn just applying CSS transform
https://pastebin.com/LHZtN5r2